# How to get hal_json format as Drupal output?

Tags: 8

I installed Drupal 8 and these modules on my host:

- HAL
- HTTP Basic Authentication
- RESTful Web Services
- REST UI
- Serialization

These are all core modules except REST UI.

According to Drupal tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xCndQQVJsg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnZo5lMICKc) when I enter this URL, Drupal would show JSON format of node 1:

```
www.example.com/node/1?format=hal_json
```

But it shows the normal (HTML) view of node 1.

What should I do to get JSON or hal+json format as output?

Comment: To improve your question, please provide a link to the modules you installed, and the tutorials you tried.

Answer (score 4):

Send a GET to http://theurl.com/node/1?_format=hal+json

This should work! Make sure you enabled the Resources to read out nodes.

Comment: I think the string should be ?_format=hal_json